# Vue deploy with Apache: routes don't work in history mode

Tags: apache, vue.js, vue-router

I'm having trouble deploying a vue application (no database nor server-side code) with Apache (HTTPs too). This is my .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
ServerName mydomain.me
ServerAlias www.mydomain.me
DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.me/dist
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/mydomain.me/dist>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.me [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydomain.me
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

When I access mydomain, the frontpage is correctly loaded (the index.html built with `npm run build`), however none of the routes work (i.e. /portfolio).

If, however, I switch my router mode from `history` to `hash`, things work (`/#/portfolio`), but I want to keep `history` mode active.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ended up with a solution - not sure if it's the best one but it works for my case.

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain.me-le-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.me
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.me
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.me/dist
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/mydomain.me/dist>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.me [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydomain.me
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.me/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.me/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**.htaccess on /var/www/mydomain.me/dist**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The important part here is that you have to enable `AllowOverride` from the `ssl.conf` version of your .conf file. If you only have it enabled in `sites-available/mydomain.me.conf` but you're forcing HTTPS, it won't take effect.

Answer (score 6):

Your case is tricky because those `RewriteCond`s and `RewriteRule` you have seem to be redirecting to HTTPS.

If that's so, here's something that might work:

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain.me-le-ssl.conf**

```html
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.me
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.me
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.me/dist
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/mydomain.me/dist>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.me [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydomain.me
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.me/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.me/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**.htaccess on /var/www/mydomain.me/dist**

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using a Let's Encrypt certificate so HTTPs is mandatory. When I try that config, I get the following error logs upon Apache restart:

apache2[3848]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 21 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain.me.conf
apache2[3848]: RewriteBase: only valid in per-directory config files
apache2[3848]: The Apache error log may have more information.
systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
sudo[3842]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server

Comment: This seemed to work but after clearing my cache it didn't :( What happens is that I'm getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", and when I check the source for my JS files they output HTML (see http://prntscr.com/j0swej). Any idea why?

Comment: What's the full path of that file `app...js` file?

Comment: All my JS files point to /static/js/[file.js]. If I try to open them in a separate tab, I get a blank result.
This is my current full config file by the way - http://prntscr.com/j0y5jj. I was (wrongly) updating my HTTP conf file while what I need to have working is HTTPs (443). Nevertheless, can't get JS files to work with it.

Comment: I meant I needed to see the whole path of the app.js file you were trying in the address bar of the browser. Anyway, I have added what I believe could be an improvement over the version you told you are using; try it out.